# Some zero-sum game

Tags: game-theory

Consider a game with the following payoff-matrix

$\textbf{M}=\begin{array}{c|c c c c}
\! & A & B & C & D \\
\hline 
A & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
B & -1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
C & 1 & -1 & 0 & -1 \\
D & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}$

It's easy to see that there are no saddle points or dominated strategies. So I tryed to find a mixed strategy envolving all possible strategies $A,B,C,D$, but I failed with this step. It means the game has a solution in a 3x3 or 2x2 subgame. I let work a computer (http://banach.lse.ac.uk/) and I obtained two optimal strategies, note them $\mathsf{S}=(A,B,C,D)=(1/3,1/3,1/3,0)$ (I guess obtained as a solution of $(A,B,C)\times(A,B,C)$ subgame) and $\mathsf{T}=(1/2,0,0,1/2)$ (which might be obtained as a solution of $(A,D)\times(A,D)$ subgame). If I understand Minimax Theorem (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinimaxTheorem.html) correctly, there will be infinitely many optimal strategies in form $\mathsf{O}=\lambda\mathsf{S}+(1-\lambda)\mathsf{T}=\left(\frac{3-\lambda}{6},\frac{\lambda}{3},\frac{\lambda}{3},\frac{1-\lambda}{2}\right)$ for $0\le\lambda\le1$.

Now a task. Prove explicitely, that every non-optimal strategy $\mathsf R=(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta)\neq\mathsf O$ is at most as good as $\mathsf O$. My main problem here is to deal with expected payoff, which should be equaled to $0$. How can be then $\mathsf R$ worse? :)

It is also possible, that I misunderstood something, so everything written above may be completely wrong. The most problematic place for me is an acquisition of $\mathsf T$. Where did it come from? Is that really from subgame $(A,D)\times(A,D)$? If so, it si a little bit weird for me, because you have a "singular payoff" matrix and there every strategy $(x,1-x)$ is "optimal", or am I wrong? :)

And last few questions. Consider payoff matrix $\textbf{M}'=k\cdot\textbf{M}$ for some nonzero $k\in\mathbb R$ (every possible outcome is multiplied by $k$). Then expected payoffs and optimal strategy should stay without any changes, right? So, why? And consider matrix $\textbf{M}''=\textbf{M}+c=\left(a_{ij}+c\right)_{4\times4}$ (every outcome is raised by $c\in\mathbb R$). Then optimal strategies remain same and the expect payoff for row player will be $c$, ok? And again, why? :)

Thx a lot for any help.

Comment: Please ask ONE question not a list if you want good answers.

Comment: Why $R$'s expected payoff should be equal to zero if $R$ is not optimal? It does not make sense.

Comment: Yea, I probably wrote it in a quite non-comprehensible form. Assume we have two players. $P_1$ plays $\mathsf O$-strategy and $P_2$ plays $\mathsf R$-strategy. Then expect value of $P_1$ should be $0$. Correct? And now, what will be expected value of $P_2$?

Comment: Ok, thank you. And could I count payoffs of $P_1$ as a function of $\mathsf R$?

Comment: I tryed this, denote $\mathcal P\left(P_1(\mathsf O)\rightarrow P_2(\mathsf R)\right)$ payoff of player $P_1$ using strategy $\mathsf O$ against player $P_2$ with $\mathsf R$-strategy, then
$\mathcal P\left(P_1(\mathsf O)\rightarrow P_2(\mathsf R)\right)=\frac{3-\lambda}{6}(0\cdot\alpha+\beta-\gamma+0\cdot\delta)+\frac{ \lambda}{3}(-\alpha+0\cdot\beta+\gamma+\delta)+\frac{\lambda}{3}(\alpha-\beta+0 \cdot \gamma-\delta)+\frac{1-\lambda}{2}(0\cdot\alpha-\beta+\gamma+0\cdot\delta)= \frac{3-\lambda}{6}(\beta-\gamma)-\frac{\lambda}{3}(\beta-\gamma)-\frac{1- \lambda}{2}(\beta-\gamma)=0$

Comment: Thus $P_1$ should have a payoff always equaled to $0$ regardless on enemy's strategy, or not?

Comment: I was wrong, sorry: any pure strategy gives payoff zero against $O$. So any mixed strategy payoff (which is an average of the payoff of the pure strategies) also must give the same payoff against $O$. So (against $O$) no strategy can do better than $O$ or any other strategy...

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. Last question, from which subgame (and how) was strategy $(1/2,0,0,1/2)$ obtained?

Comment: First, for game-theorists "subgame" means something very different. Second, you do not need to use these "subgames" to solve for the eq.  Let $p=(p_A,p_B,p_C,1-p_A-pB-p_C)$ solve for the linear system (using elimination and substitution): $U_1(A,p)=0$, $U_2(B,p)=0$, $U_3(C,p)=0$ and $U_4(D,p)=0$ and you will get the solution you found above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p=(p_A,p_B,p_C,1-p_A-p_B-p_C)$.
Then if we look for an equilibrium where all strategies are player with positive prob we get:

$\begin{align*} &U_1(A,p)=p_B-p_C,\\
&U_1(B,p)=1-2p_A-p_B,\\
&U_1(C,p)=2p_A+p_C-1,\\
&U_1(D,p)=p_C-p_B.
\end{align*}$

So $U_1(A,p)=U_1(D,p)\Leftrightarrow p_C=p_B\Rightarrow U_1(A,p)=0$.
And so $U_1(C,p)=0\Rightarrow $p_A=(1-p_B)/2$.

You can see that $p_B=p_C=0$ also satisfies all below so you can also get an eq. where only $A$ and $D$ are played with positive prob. but you must then have $p_A=(1-p_B)/2=1/2$.